# (Ubuntu 17.10) Disable touchpad bottom-right corner right-click

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I want to turn the touchpad's bottom-right corner click from a right-click into a normal left-click. (Basically the entire touchpad will produce only a left click.)

I have read many posts referring to using synclient commands, but synclient is not installed on Ubuntu 17.10.

My laptop is a Yoga 910, I believe it has a synaptics touchpad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In wayland (default Ubuntu session, not the Ubuntu-XORG), change a gnome setting click-method from 'default' to 'fingers', then the entire trackpad will become a giant touchpad without any software buttons.

Single finger click = left click,
Two finger click = right click,
Three finger click = middle click

[ubuntu terminal showing the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJAXK.png)